# gnuplot double chart from csv

Tags: csv, charts, gnuplot

I can't make a double bar chart by age and genre. This is my data:

```
"20 to 30","Man",7
"20 to 30","Woman",5
"30 to 40","Man",3
"30 to 40","Woman",6
"40 to 50","Man",9
"40 to 50","Woman",2
```

I'm trying something like:

[image]

I've tried several options, like:

```
plot 'data.csv' using 3:xtic(2) with boxes ls 1,\
   'data.csv' using 3:xtic(2) with boxes ls 2
```

But it show like this:

[image: nup]

Comment: There is already a solution to this:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/10786085/7766168](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10786085/7766168) Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this solution, but I couldn't do it because it isn't the same source structure. Mi csv have grouped data with a result, and in the other solution there is a categorical variable with several columns.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can always preprocess your data with external tools such that it can be easily plotted with gnuplot's plotting styles. But in your case (with several string columns) I'm not sure whether gnuplot offers a suitable plotting style. At least I couldn't find (yet) a comparable example on [www.gnuplot.info](http://www.gnuplot.info) or anywhere else.

Ethan's script is shorter, but only works nicely because the categories "male" and "female" are strictly alternating in the data.

In my more general approach they could be random, but then you need to create lists of unique parameters, (in your case age and gender). For example, in Python this simply would be the command `set(list)`. In gnuplot you have to implement this yourself.

Then plot the data in loops using the ternary operator (check "help ternary") to "filter" the data. Note that I'm not using any histogram style but simply `with boxes`.
With a few more parameters `gap` and `boxWidth` and a list of colors you can easily fine tune your graph. I hope you can adapt the script below to your needs.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.0, except for 5.0.4 for some unknown reason)

```
### grouped bar chart with several string columns
reset session

# data can be random, xtics of bars will be in order of first occurrence
$Data <<EOD
"20 to 30", "male",   7
"30 to 40", "male",   3
"40 to 50", "female", 2
"40 to 50", "male",   9
"30 to 40", "female", 6
"20 to 30", "female", 5
EOD

set datafile separator comma
colX    = 1     # here: age
colSubX = 2     # here: gender
colY    = 3

# create unique lists of entries
addUniq(list,col) = list.(_s=' "'.strcol(col).'"', strstrt(list,_s)>0 ? '' : _s)
Xs = SubXs = ''
stats $Data u (   Xs=addUniq(Xs,   colX))    nooutput
stats $Data u (SubXs=addUniq(SubXs,colSubX)) nooutput
N        = words(Xs)
M        = words(SubXs)
X(i)     = word(Xs,i)
SubX(i)  = word(SubXs,i)

# bar chart settings
gap         = 0.3    # relative gap between bar groups
boxWidth    = 0.8    # relative boxwidth
boxGrid     = (1.-gap)/M
xPos(n,m)   = n - 0.5 + gap/2. + boxGrid*(m-0.5)
yPos(n,m,c) = strcol(colX) eq X(n) && strcol(colSubX) eq SubX(m) ? column(c) : NaN
colors      = "#0000ff #ff0000 #00ff00"
color(i)    = word(colors,i)

set style fill solid 1.0
set key top left noautotitle
set xtics out nomirror
set xrange[0.5:N+0.5]
set yrange[0:]
set offset 0,0,graph 0.1, 0

plot for [n=1:N] for [m=1:M] \
     $Data u (xPos(n,m)):(yPos(n,m,colY)):(boxWidth*boxGrid) w boxes lc rgb color(m), \
     for [m=1:M] NaN ti SubX(m) w boxes lc rgb color(m), \
     for [n=1:N] $Data u (n):(NaN):xtic(X(n))
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

By using the same code but simply swapping the column numbers, i.e. `colX = 2` and `colSubX = 1` you will get the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SUDHANSHU SHEKHAR CHAURASIA was correct to point to an earlier answer. Your case is very similar and so is the solution.

```
$Data <<EOD
"20 to 30", "male",   7
"20 to 30", "female", 5
"30 to 40", "male",   3
"30 to 40", "female", 6
"40 to 50", "male",   9
"40 to 50", "female", 2
EOD
set datafile sep comma

set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster
set style fill solid

plot $Data every 2::0 using 3:xtic(1) title "Man", \
     $Data every 2::1 using 3 title "Woman"
```

[image]

Pulling the title from column 2 might be possible but I think it would depend on the exact version of gnuplot you are using.